# ERROR 1064 (42000) creating table MySQL

Tags: mysql

I try to build my own website, and at my website I ask people to enter their name and write a little story. When they are done, they hit submit, and it sends the information to my database. I work with MySQL, and I want to create a table where I can store the information in. This is my MySQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE names (
    name PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    message NOT NULL,
    IPv4 NOT NULL,
    browser NOT NULL,
    date NOT NULL,
    time NOT NULL,
);
```

But when I enter this in my command prompt, it says:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
    check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
    right syntax to use near 'PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, message NOT NULL, 
    IPv4 NOT NULL, browser NOT NULL, date NO' at line 1
```

Can you tell me what I did wrong and how to fix this? I don't know if it's helpful, but I've included my PHP script too. It can be a little messy with names because I had to translate the variables to English. My PHP code is (I created it before I created the table, and as you see I did manage to set up my database 'names', also I want to call my table 'names'):

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$user = 'user';
$password = 'Login';
$host = 'localhost:3036';
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
date_default_timezone_set('UTC+1');
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$time = date("H:i:s");
$connect = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
if (! $connect)
{
    $error = mysql_error();
    print "Sorry, could not connect: $error";
}
print "Connected!";
$database = "USE names";
$table = "INSERT INTO names (name, message, IPv4, browser, date, time) VALUES ($name, $message, $ip, $browser, $date, $time)";
if (! $database)
{
    $error=mysql_error();
    echo "\nCould not find database! Error: $mysql_error";
}
if (! $table)
{
    $error=mysql_error();
    echo "\nCould not write to database! Error: $error";
}
$close = mysql_close($connect);
if (! $close )
{
    $error=mysql_error();
    echo "\nCould not close connection! Error: $error";
}
echo "\nBedankt $name!";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your last line shouldn't contain a comma `,` since it's the last line and no more variables will come after it. so the code should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE names (
    name char(40) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    message varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    IPv4 char(50) NOT NULL,
    browser char(20) NOT NULL,
    date datetime NOT NULL,
    time int NOT NULL
);
```

Note that the last line, `time NOT NULL` doesn't have a comma at the end.

MYSQL aren't very helpful with there error messages they mostly tell you that you need to read your code again until you get it right.

Also you haven't told MYSQL what sort of data will go into these fields. Is it a char or a number? You need to specify this like, `data int primary key` or `data2 char(40) not null`. On int's you don't need to specify the length of the variable but on chars you do.

Comment: I have tried this, but I keep getting the same syntax Error.

Comment: @user274595 Updated my answer!

Answer (score 0):

There is an error with your query to database - you cant place `,` before `)`.

However `INSERT` values should be placed between `'`, like `'value'`. It's unnecessary, but it's good practice.

You can "generate" your query by adding some `implode` functions, like this:

```
$data = array("name" => $_POST["name"]);
$into = implode(", ", array_keys($data));
$values = "'".implode("', '", $data)."'";
$query = "INSERT INTO user ($into) VALUES ($values);");
```

Generating queries should help you omit future syntax errors.